# SCSSPHP ignoring @import directive or relative path issue?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using SCSSPHP and my folder structure is as follows:

```
/app/assets
        /css
            /css.php
            /mysite.scss
            /bootstrap
                /bootstrap.scss
                    /bootstrap
                        /_variables.scss
                        /... more bootstrap stuff ...
```

My css.php looks like this:

```
<?php

    require "../../vendor/scssphp/scss.inc.php";

    scss_server::serveFrom(".");
```

Now, when I try to load the URL `/assets/css/css.php/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss`, all I get is the raw contents of the file. E.g. all of the `@import` directives seem to be ignored during SCSS processing.

```
/* compiled by scssphp v0.0.12 on Mon, 28 Jul 2014 14:04:38 -0400 (0.025s) */

@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
/* ... more bootstrap stuff ... */
```

My assumption is that SCSSPHP doesn't like the relative paths, even though they are correct. So I changed the `variables` import to make the path relative to the `css.php` file:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
/* ... more bootstrap stuff ... */
```

After that, SCSSPHP seems to have recognized the path, perhaps. But it only strips the import directive and leaves me with this rendered CSS:

```
/* compiled by scssphp v0.0.12 on Mon, 28 Jul 2014 14:06:25 -0400 (0.129s) */

/* NOTICE: variables missing! */
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
/* ... more bootstrap stuff ... */
```

Looking in the cached SCSS folder, I see the cached bootstrap imports CSS, which acts like it definitely found the file to import, but didn't actually do the import!

```
a:1:{i:0;s:37:"./bootstrap/bootstrap/_variables.scss";}
```

Not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is, but I would recommend specifying an absolute path in your `serveFrom` call to ensure that the path resolution is not the issue, before looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks - same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell SCSSPHP to look for imports relative to the actual path of the file, so you would have to do

```
$scss->addImportPaths('app/assets/css/bootstrap/');
```

(or however your call is built) to look for imported files based on the path of the actual SCSS file, see: [Documentation - scssphp / Import Paths](https://leafo.github.io/scssphp/docs/#import-paths)